# How can I use lambda complete this function?

Tags: python, lambda

I want to use lambda to finish the following function:

```
for i in range(0, len(testingList)):
    testingList[i] = testing[i][1:-1]
```

I don't know how to use lambda to build it.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Could you tell us what your function is supposed to do?

Comment: @thg435 looks like an attempt to strip the first and last element from each item in a sequence... I'd guess `[el[1:-1] for el in testingList]` is what this will end up as...

Comment: This looks like a simple assignment; you can shortened that to a list comprehension if you like. I don't see a need for `lambda`.

Comment: Actually, I am not familiar with lambda, and I'd like to know that how can I use lambda in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make that fit in a `lambda` you'd have to make it one expression. A list comprehension can do that:

```
somename = lambda tl: [elem[1:-1] for elem in tl]
```

Call this with `testingList`:

```
testingList = somename(testingList)
```